# ListView with Expanded when not scrollable

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a menu with list of ExpansionTile and a footer, when the ExpansionTile is not expanded (not scrollable) the footer stay on the bottom of screen, but when the ExpansionTile is expanded (scrollable) the children of ExpansionTile push the footer out of screen.

For a clearer illustration, please see the following image

[image]

this my current code, but it's not a best way I think

checking is scrollable or not

```
checkIsScrollable(BuildContext context) {
if (Scrollable.of(context).position.minScrollExtent >=
    Scrollable.of(context).position.maxScrollExtent) {
  setState(() {
    scrollable = false;
  });
} else {
  setState(() {
    scrollable = true;
  });
}
```

this the listview

```
ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
  children: [
    LimitedBox(
      maxHeight: !scrollable
          ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 84
          : double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 24,
          ),
          Text(
            "Account".toUpperCase(),
            style: ThemeApp.appBarTextStyle(),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 24,
          ),
          photoProfile(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          menuProfile(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          AccountContent.customerCare1(
            context: context,
            onExpansionChanged: (_) {
              Future.delayed(
                Duration(milliseconds: 101),
                () {
                  checkIsScrollable(context);
                },
              );
            },
          ),
          AccountContent.sellWithUs(
            context: context,
            onExpansionChanged: (_) {
              Future.delayed(
                Duration(milliseconds: 101),
                () {
                  checkIsScrollable(context);
                },
              );
            },
          ),
          AccountContent.customerCare2(
            context: context,
            onExpansionChanged: (_) {
              Future.delayed(
                Duration(milliseconds: 101),
                () {
                  checkIsScrollable(context);
                },
              );
            },
          ),
          !scrollable
              ? Expanded(
                  child: Container(),
                )
              : Container(),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 18,
                        width: 18,
                        color: ThemeApp.borderColor,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Text(
                        "LOGOUT",
                        style: ThemeApp.subTitleTextStyle(),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: BorderedButton(
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          "assets/icons/icon_whatsapp.svg",
                          color: ThemeApp.primaryColor,
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          openWhatsapp();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 17,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: BorderedButton(
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          "assets/icons/icon_instagram.svg",
                          color: ThemeApp.primaryColor,
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          openInstagram();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 17,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: BorderedButton(
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(
                          "assets/icons/icon_mail.svg",
                          color: ThemeApp.primaryColor,
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          openMail();
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Try to add your code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `Column` inside of `LayoutBuilder` and with a `ConstrainedBox`, set The minHeight of the Column to maxHeight of `LayoutBuilder`:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
        return  SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                YourListView(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                ),
                YourFooter(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your question correctly but i guess you need too use Stack widget which always stays your footer on it's place even your page is Scrollable.

Comment: No, it's not what I want, I want the footer scrollable too (after ExpansionTile is expanded and push the footer out of screen)

Answer (score 1):

The footer you don't want to scroll, make the Column having two children and inside the column add another column and put the scrollable data inside that and wrap that with the SingleChildScrolView.

```
Column(
children: [
SingleChildScrollView(
child: Column(
children: [
// your scrollable data here
],
Column(
children: [
// Footer not scrollable
],),
],
```

Comment: NO, I want to scroll the footer too

Comment: Then you have to wrap the column with SingleChildScrollView